# How do I execute "bundle install" on a nodejs heroku buildpack?

Tags: heroku

package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "bundle install",
    "install": "cake build",
    "start": "coffee server/app.coffee"
  }
```

My build step (`cake build`) invokes sass, which is a gem executable. My Gemfile has sass. When I push to heroku, I get the error `sh: bundle: not found"`. What's the correct way of making the `sass` command available in time for the build step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run multiple processes, each based on different languages, you can either use heroku-buildpack-multi or even just write your own custom buildpack! The former option is much easier, but may not work in all situations.